# Not able to read params send through AJAX using express and body parser

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, ejs, body-parser

I am sending form data through AJAX and reading it on server side using expressjs and body parser. I am posting data successfully but no data is displayed on server side.

JS (through AJAX is done):

```
    function ajaxCallPost(url, elementid, params)
    {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
     }
   };
   xhttp.open("POST", url , false);
   xhttp.send(params);
 }
```

Server side code (expressjs and body parser):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var event = {
  title:'Sample Title',
  location:'Sample Location',
  startDate:'Sample Date',
  endDate:'Sample Date'
};
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  event.title = req.body.txtEventTitle;
  event.location = req.body.txtEventLocation;
  event.startDate = req.body.txtEventStartDate;
  event.endDate = req.body.txtEventEndDate;

  res.render('commonProcess',{data:event});
});
```

Posting data (JS):

```
 ajaxCallPost('/','loaddiv',params);
```

Empty Data is displayed on EJS Template

Comment: What is `params`?

Comment: params is a formdata combined using '&' so if there are two textboxes name as txtfname and txtlname params value would be txtfname='john'&txtlname='watson' like that

Comment: I don't think body-parser would do anything with your data. It doesn't expect this format in the body of request. This format of data should be part of url like `/some-url/?xtfname=john&txtlname=watson` also the `'` (single qute) should not be there. In this case i would strongly recommend to use json since you are using javascript on both the client as well as the server. It makes a lot of sence and also makes it much easier to work with the data.

Comment: Can u show your body parser middleware?

Comment: How body parser would read json data which I passed?

Comment: body parser middleware:                                            app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: while posting json through AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) Body parser is not reading data